# How can I send the data I get from the api with workmanager as a notification?

Tags: android, mvvm, push-notification, retrofit, android-workmanager

My Worker Class

```kotlin
class NotificationWorker(
    private val context: Context,
    params: WorkerParameters,
) : CoroutineWorker(context, params) {

    private val viewModel: QuoteSunshineViewModel by lazy {
        QuoteSunshineViewModel()
    }
    
    override suspend fun doWork(): Result = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
        try {
            createNotificationChannel()
            
            val quoteSunshineDatabase: QuoteSunshineDatabase? = QuoteSunshineDatabase.getQuoteSunshineDatabase(context)
            val myCategories = quoteSunshineDatabase?.myCategoriesDao()?.getAll()

            withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                if (myCategories.isNullOrEmpty()){
                    viewModel.getQuoteSunshine(CATEGORIES.random())
                }
                else {
                    viewModel.getQuoteSunshine(category = myCategories.random().category)
                }
                viewModel.quoteSunshine.observeForever {
                    sendNotification(it.quote, it.author)
                }
            }
            Result.success()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Result.failure()
        }
    }
}
```

Initial Worker in mainactivity

```kotlin
val constraints = Constraints.Builder()
    .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.UNMETERED)
    .build()

val repeatingRequest = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<NotificationWorker>(
    15,
    TimeUnit.MINUTES) .setConstraints(constraints)
    .build()

WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
    "NotificationWork",
    ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP,
    repeatingRequest
)
```

I'm pulling data from api using viewmodel and I want to push notification every 15 minutes, how can I do that?

I think there is a problem in the doWork() method, sometimes the notification does not send, I wonder how can I get the data stably?

Comment: 1. You should not use `ViewModel` in a `Worker`, use the underlying `Repository` or the `Datasource` to get the data directly. 2. WorkManager's periodic tasks are not going to be always exact on time.